# Present simple passive/present perfect passive

Tags: tenses, passive-voice

I am confused/have been confused about their usage for a long time.

I have seen different people use them in different ways.
From Internet searches, i have known that **present simple passive** is used when we mean  *regularity*, or *state*.

For example-•I am done( state)
•Dishes are usually done by him( regularity)

And **present perfect passive**, when we want to say *someone has done the action and its completed now*

But as I said I have heard people (be it native speakers ,news reporters) say sentences that could have been used in other tense too,one of the many examples-

• Is anybody injured?
• has anybody been injured?

Could anybody clear this confusion.

Comment: *Is anybody injured?* Does anybody currently have an injury. (*Is anybody missing a finger?*) *Has anybody been injured?* Was anybody the *victim* of an injury. (*Did anybody get their finger cut off?*) It's very possible to have been injured in the past but still suffer from it today. Although I'm not sure if that clarifies your question, because I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

Comment: @Jason Bassford Actually what I wanted to say is that these two tenses seem interchangeable to me. Like I hear reporters say- ' The Government is asked to make some changes' and sometimes 'The government has been asked to make some changes'. What I take from your answer is that in 1) sentence ' 'Somebody asks the Government to make some changes' and in 2) 'somebody asked the Government to make some changes in the past and it is expected to make some changes in the present.? Sorry, I may sound disoriented.